# Get time from Time Server using java

Tags: java

I am working on licensing and I need to get the current date and time from time server, that is irrespective of the time and date of the system.

I have tried `Joda Time API` and some classes of Java like `TimeZone` and I have seen that the value which I get is actually based on the system current time and date.

I have managed to get the `TimeZone` of the client machine to which it is set and now I want to query the time server for the current time of that `TimeZone` which will be not dependent on the system current date and time.

Will be helpful if I get some suggestions!

Comment: "Will be helpful if I get some working code." - That's not how SO works ...

Comment: Tell us what you have done so far...

Comment: May be [this can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time)

Comment: Here is one from another question. Never used it myself.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19962190/4418511

Comment: Changed my mind, now I think @Sanjeev 's link is better.  Here is the answer from the question he linked, that I particularly liked. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13547204/4418511

Comment: My link was probably good for clientside stuff, though.  His is exactly what you need.

Comment: Are you worried about people faking a system time by changing the system clock?

Comment: I have tried the solutions that are present in the question with which my present questions has been marked duplicate with, the solutions return time of the system clock or get modified when the system clock is changed.

Comment: @GC_ Yes, that is what I am worrying about. I want to get the current time directly from the time server which won't get modified in any way when people change the system clock.

Comment: Also, you could even use SSL, if you really want to give yourself and the hackers a headache.

Comment: Did you check the answer I linked it, in the question @Sanjeev linked?  I think that should not be your server time.

Comment: @GC_ Yes I have tried that before posting this question here, that code does gives the time from some server but when I change the system time of my computer, the result of the program (fetched time from the server) changes too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TIMEAPI` available [here](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now).

---

Alternatively, you can do some `web-scraping`. 
[www.time.is/GMT](http://time.is/GMT) will give you current GMT time.

You can easily scrape the page with `JSOUP` or some other library.
FYI, the `time` is displayed within the element with the `id` of `twd` and the date is displayed within the element with the id `dd`.

Comment: It is very dangerous to use web-scraping . because if the web page format is changed then we end up with trouble. It is better idea to use API exposed by some standard time servers .